# image_default_size doesn't change in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, image, size, default

I'd like to change the default size for images within posts. I've tried to edit both the `/wp-admin/options.php` page and the `functions.php` file, but none affect the size. They do work for the default alignment and the default link, but not for the size.

Here's the snippet from my functions.php file

```
    add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'default_attachment_display_settings' );

function default_attachment_display_settings() {
 update_option( 'image_default_align', 'right' );
 update_option( 'image_default_size', 'large' );
}
```

The images keep showing up as "full size".

Answer (score 1):

That option seems to be ignored by the editor, but this works:

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', '_my_reset_image_insert_settings' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', '_my_reset_image_insert_settings' );
function _my_reset_image_insert_settings() {
  ?>
    <script>
      if ( typeof setUserSetting !== 'undefined' ) {
        //setUserSetting( 'align', 'none' ); // none || left || center || right
        setUserSetting( 'imgsize', 'large' ); // thumbnail || medium || large || full
        //setUserSetting( 'urlbutton', 'none' ); // none || file || post
      }
    </script>
  <?php
}
```

Snippet made by @azaozz
Source: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/35101#comment:15

Answer (score 0):

you can do the changes in `.css` for that particular class.

Comment: use [custom css](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/) wordpress plugin to make css effective.